# Xcode mach -o linker

Tags: ios, xcode

When i am trying to compile my project with NMSSH framework, XCode 5 says:
`Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"_OBJC_CLASS_$_NMSSHSession", referenced from: objc-class-ref in HelloWorldViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

What should I do?

Comment: Questions about software development are off-topic here, but can be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue myself. Here's what I did to fix it.

1. Open the downloaded Git repo in Finder
   [image: Finder View]
2. Open the NMSSH-iOS.xcodeproj file. *NOT* the NMSSH.xcodeproj!
3. Clean and build the project.
4. Follow the steps from the Github wiki page https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH/wiki/Build-and-use-in-your-iOS-project

Actually, this itself is on the wiki page too. I know I opened the wrong Xcode Project and it seems like a lot of people do it accidentally. So, that's what I had to do to resolve it. Also, you'll have to build the framework for either the physical device or the emulator, depending upon what you're using and add to your project depending. 
[image: Xcode]

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You need to link `NMSSH.framework` with your project.

Open **Build Phases** in your project settings and add `NMSSH.framework` into the group **Link Binary With Libraries**.

Comment: I have already linked it.I have also linked CFNetwork framework and libz.dylib as in [tutorial](https://github.com/Lejdborg/NMSSH/wiki/Build-and-use-in-your-iOS-project)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Click on the project then go to build settings and type linker flags in the search bar   
Add "-ObjC" to "Other Linker Flags"
```

Comment: No result. I also have this in output
`ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/lx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NMSSH-iOS-elmxutddgmsrhuczaeascdpivpkh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NMSSH.framework/NMSSH, missing required architecture i386 in file /Users/lx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NMSSH-iOS-elmxutddgmsrhuczaeascdpivpkh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/NMSSH.framework/NMSSH (3 slices)`

Comment: did u add i386 in architecture ?